# shellinabox @2.20: error: static declaration of 'ptsname_r' follows non-static declaration

Tags: macos, macports

From macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

*sudo port -vvv selfupdate && sudo port -vvv upgrade outdated* gives following error :

```
 --->  Computing dependencies for shellinabox.
    --->  Fetching archive for shellinabox
    --->  shellinabox-2.20_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 doesn't seem to exist in /opt/local/var/macports/incoming/verified
    --->  Attempting to fetch shellinabox-2.20_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/shellinabox
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
    --->  Attempting to fetch shellinabox-2.20_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/shellinabox
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
    --->  Attempting to fetch shellinabox-2.20_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/shellinabox
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   293  100   293    0     0   4123      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4185
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
    --->  Building shellinabox
    Executing:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_net_shellinabox/shellinabox/work/shellinabox-2.20" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all 
    make: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_net_shellinabox/shellinabox/work/shellinabox-shellinabox-e45d8f2'
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  all-am
    make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_net_shellinabox/shellinabox/work/shellinabox-shellinabox-e45d8f2'
    depbase=`echo shellinabox/launcher.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
        /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.   -I/opt/local/include -g -std=gnu99 -Wall -pipe -Os -arch x86_64 -MT shellinabox/launcher.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o shellinabox/launcher.o shellinabox/launcher.c &&\
        mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
    shellinabox/launcher.c:772:12: error: static declaration of 'ptsname_r' follows non-static declaration
    static int ptsname_r(int fd, char *buf, size_t buflen) {
               ^
    /usr/include/stdlib.h:229:5: note: previous declaration is here
    int ptsname_r(int fildes, char *buffer, size_t buflen) __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13.4), ios(11.3), tvos(11.3), watchos(4.3));
        ^
    shellinabox/launcher.c:819:11: warning: 'ptsname_r' is only available on macOS 10.13.4 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
          if (ptsname_r (*pty, path, length)) {
              ^~~~~~~~~
    /usr/include/stdlib.h:229:5: note: 'ptsname_r' has been explicitly marked partial here
    int ptsname_r(int fildes, char *buffer, size_t buflen) __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13.4), ios(11.3), tvos(11.3), watchos(4.3));
        ^
    shellinabox/launcher.c:819:11: note: enclose 'ptsname_r' in a __builtin_available check to silence this warning
          if (ptsname_r (*pty, path, length)) {
              ^~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    make[1]: *** [shellinabox/launcher.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_net_shellinabox/shellinabox/work/shellinabox-shellinabox-e45d8f2'
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_net_shellinabox/shellinabox/work/shellinabox-shellinabox-e45d8f2'
    Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_net_shellinabox/shellinabox/work/shellinabox-2.20" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all 
    Exit code: 2
    Error: Failed to build shellinabox: command execution failed
    Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_net_shellinabox/shellinabox/main.log for details.
    Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
```

The command *shellinaboxd* gives :

dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/shellinaboxd

Reason: image not found

Abort trap: 6

The main.log : 
https://friendpaste.com/1Sq0YscWvzneKPL9s1Af2W

Comment: Have you recently updated your OS? If so, try reinstalling xcode command line tools.

Comment: OS updated today.